# javascript call array of functions with the same context

Tags: javascript, arrays, middleware

I am trying to create a callback functionality or at least that is how I name it. The main purpose is to call function from an array with the same context and to be able to call the next function in the array from the currently executing function.

This is the code that I have came up with:

```js
function callCallbackChain(context, callbackChain, params) {
    callbackChain.push(function () {
        return true;
    });
    for (var i = 0, len = callbackChain.length - 1; i < len; i++) {
        var cb   = callbackChain[i];
        var next = callbackChain[i + 1];
        if (typeof cb === "function") {
            cb.apply(context, [next].concat(params));
        }
    }
}
var callbackChain = [
    function (next, foo) {
        console.log('1 function call', arguments);
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + "function called + context:" + foo + "<br>";
        next()
    },
    function (next, foo) {
        console.log('2 function call', arguments);
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + "function called + context:" + foo + "<br>";
        next()
    },
    function (next, foo) {
        console.log('3 function call', arguments);
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + "function called + context:" + foo + "<br>";
        next()
    }
];


var d = document.querySelector("#conent");
callCallbackChain(d, callbackChain, ["param from the main function"]);
```

```html
<div id="conent">
  Initial Content
  
</div>
```

I can't seem to be able to set `next` function properly. It is something like a middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `next` function must not actually be the next function in the chain.

Its the intent to run the next function.

```js
function run(context, chain, params) {
  var inner_run = (context, chain, params, index) => {
    next = () => inner_run(context, chain, params, index + 1);
    if (index < chain.length) chain[index].apply(context, [next].concat(params));
  };
  inner_run(context, chain, params, 0);
}

var chain = [
  function (next, foo) {
    this.first = true
    console.log('first', arguments);
    next()
  },
  function (next, foo) {
    this.second = true
    console.log('second', arguments);
    // not calling next()
  },
  function (next, foo) {
    this.third = true
    console.log('third', arguments);
    next()
  }
];

var context = {};

run(context, chain, ["param"]);

console.log('context', context);
```

Comment: This one actually works for me. I've done my version but this is full working answer so I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind it on the fly:

```
var nextelem=0;
function next(params...){
 temp=nextelem;
 nextelem++;
 callbackChain[temp].bind(context)(next,...params);
}
//pass it
nextelem=1;
callbackChain[0].bind(context)(next);
```

Comment: I am still getting `undefined` context https://jsfiddle.net/xr8q7s1f/2/

Comment: the next function needs to be kind of recursive so you would have needed to pass a really complicated function. generating it dynamically should be easier...

Comment: I've manage to do it it https://jsfiddle.net/xr8q7s1f/4/ Now I will try you version

Comment: Well the code did not work as expected but it is fixed now https://jsfiddle.net/xr8q7s1f/5/

Comment: Yeah its just pseudocode, didnt wrote a full answer